# How to show the success message in redirecting page

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: "new_crop_image.php",
                        data: ({'crop': result.toDataURL()}),
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        if(data == 'SUCCESS'){
                            window.location.assign('php/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $ssmid;?>'); 
                            } 
                        },
                        error:function(error){
                            alert('n');
                        }
                    });
```

For my question is in timeline.php for this page i want show one success message how to show???

Comment: You want to show success message on the url like: php/timeline.php?id=1 , right?

Comment: before redirection right?

Comment: how about putting a `Success Message` text on `php/timeline.php`

Comment: No,this one already done,this code work fine,data == success means it will going to timeline.php this also working fine,for me i want show one message for this page timeline.php

Comment: No After redirection

Comment: You want dynamic message for every time or static?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameter in url and based on that parameter you can show that message in redirecting page.

Another option you can set it through session or cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the value for `$ssmid`??

Is it coming from php file??

If so you should echo that in php file(`json_encode()`) in php file like this.

```
$data['message'] = "SUCCESS";
$data['id'] = 12;// what id you want to redirect
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then access in `success()`

```
alert(data);
if(data.message == "SUCCESS"){
       window.location.assign('php/timeline.php?id='+data.id +'&message='+data.message);

}
```

If you want to send more data, append in the url.

Comment: Redirecting should be working fine pa,how to show success message in that redirect page

Comment: Url must come like this only timeline.php?id=SSM_offline128 after id passing another data means URL should be wrong,so that page should not be working

Comment: you have spaces in id?? use `url_encode()` in php file before `json_encode()`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**
You can pass **message** parameter in url as:

```
if(data == 'SUCCESS'){
     window.location.assign('php/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $ssmid;?>&message ='+data); 
},
```

And catch the message parameter as **`message = $_GET['message'];`** in *timeline.php*

Comment: Now i am getting correct answer,but someone directly come to the URL means i want redirect to this page timeline.php?id=SSM_offline128, current page is  timeline.php?id=SSM_offline128&message=SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.assign('php/timeline.php?status=1&id=<?php echo $ssmid;?>');`

pass variable "status" and check in **"timeline.php"** if status is set and and is equal to one than show a message.

`if(isset($_REQUEST['status']) and  $_REQUEST['status'] === 1)
{
  echo "Sucess Message type here in div or in else"
}`

Comment: Url must come like this only timeline.php?id=SSM_offline128 after id passing another data means URL should be wrong,so that page should not be working

Comment: can you pass like 
window.location.assign('php/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $ssmid;?>&status=1');

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the message in URL then you can use like below :

```
var params = {"message" : "--- your message to show ---","id" : "<?php echo $ssmid;?>"};
$.post('php/timeline.php',params,function(dataHtml) 
{
     $(body).html(dataHtml);
});
```